# Why use Ember.js with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, frontend, backend

I have been wondering for some time why should I use Ember in combination with Rails?

RoR has templating system, Ember has one.

They both have:

- models
- views
- partials
- etc.

Can anyone explain to me why should I use them in a combination?

Comment: the MVC structure in Ember applies to the client side of the application. If you go with something like this you can easily reduce your Rails app to a RESTful JSON API and separate concerns more consistently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beauty of Ember is that it's completely client side. SPA's are only run on the frontend and therefore aren't able to interact with a db directly. You can use any backend you want as long as it responds in a way that corresponds with your data adapter.

As you pointed out, RoR has it's own templating system. They both have models, view, and partials. The difference is that RoR does server side rendering. The client makes a call to your backend, it compiles those templates and whatever information it needs,then it sends back a fully formed html document. It goes through that process for every single call.

Using Ember, you don't use server side rendering at all. It's all done on the client. Everything is dynamically loaded in. You make a call to an API and it returns the information you need in order to build the page.

I've personally never used RoR with Ember. I've used elixir/phoenix and Node/express both as backend APIs. The fact is you need to use Ember with some sort of backend or it's somewhat limited in what it can do.

RoR on the other hand can be a complete system on its own. When using RoR in conjunction with Ember, you use RoR as a simple endpoint to grab and store data from.

Personally, I like using Ember as my frontend because I can decouple my front and back ends easily that way. Don't feel limited to RoR. You can use any language/backend you want to create an API to fuel Ember, but if you are using Ember you do need to choose some backend to fuel your API and interact with the DB.